# Stuck in tty1 after booting from Windows USB

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

So I made a bootable windows USB with winusb. Booted from it and then decided to make a partition to install windows 10 onto.

So I restarted my pc and Booted into ubuntu only I get this screen where t he final line is start show Plymouth boot screen.

And then it boots into tty1 (not that I know what this is. Assuming it's ubuntu without a GUI.)

I've tried ctrl alt f7 and updates etc. Not sure what's happened. 
I didn't install windows because when I started the process there were no partitions that it could be installed onto.

Please help! I also wrote over my recovery disk with a windows USB which was silly but ah well.

I'm using 16.04.1 :)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Add this to your post.

Comment: Im using 16.04.1 :)